# Different logo on homepage

Tags: themes, customization, css

I have uploaded a file as my main logo within the theme settings but would like a different logo on the main page. The theme I am using has a custom css option within the theme settings, can I use custom css to only change it on the front page and not the rest of the site?

Theme: http://demo.ghostpool.com/?theme=bounce-bp

Comment: Your question needs to be considerably more specific.
Please show us the code for the logo in index.php

Comment: Sorry, here are my php files: 

index php- http://pastebin.com/YEMnpR2g

header php- http://pastebin.com/n7vdZdZ3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the theme designer has a means for you to use a different logo on the homepage. Looking at your `header.php` on lines 83-93.

If your theme detects that this is the front page, the title is enclosed with an `<h1>` tag, otherwise it is enclosed in a `<div>`. Both have `id='logo'`.

If you can add custom css, you could use [css image replacement](http://onwebdev.blogspot.com/2011/04/css-image-replacement-tutorial.html) to replace this `<h1>` tag with a different image on your homepage.

Answer (score 0):

at header.php you can found this tags:

```
<div id="logo" style="">             
    <span class="logo-details">Bounce |   Example Homepage 1</span>
    <a href="http://demo.ghostpool.com/bounce" title="Bounce"><span class="default-logo"></span></a>                    
</div>
```

You just need access the a style-colorchoose.css at line 43 and change image path at class .default-logo, if you inspect using chrome developer tool you can find this class calling a logo from CSS using this class I mentioned.

Know if this theme offer a solution to change logo it's other way they cannot help you.

Contact me if you need a help.

Comment: Yes, the theme offers a solution to upload a logo which I have uploaded already. The problem I have is that i need a different logo on on only 1 page(homepage). I found a css file which references the themes colors and it shows this:

/* Logo */
.default-logo {
background-image: url(lib/images/logo-darkblue.png);
}

Comment: But this action change a logo every pages.

To change only to home, you need saw how class is applied to home, using a inspector at chrome you can saw all classes applied to body and using this you can add a exception adding line after default-logo this way:

`.classe-home-used .default-logo { background-image: url(http://yoursite.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/logo-onlyhome.png); }`

Comment: That darkblue.png is the default logo for the theme, it was replaced when I uploaded a logo using the option in the theme settings. Here is the site: http://are.massideation.com/

Comment: The `.default-logo` class only gets applied if you haven't specified an image in the theme options panel.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this. Let's go.

### 1. Just Header File

Open your **header.php** and find when logo is displaying and add conditional home tag. Something like this:

```
<?php if(is_home()) { ?>
<!-- your custom logo for home here -->
<?php } else { ?>
<!-- your theme logo function here -->
<?php } ?>
```

### 2. Using CSS Background Image

Open your **header.php** and go to  tag. Add the **body_class()** function.

```
<body <?php body_class($class); ?>>
```

Now, you can customize any element on home with CSS. For Example:

```
body.home .default-logo {background-image:url(your-custom-logo-for-home.jpg) !important;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use *vanilla* CSS. I wasn't able to reach your site to give you the exact CSS. But, here's an example using the **Twenty Twenty** theme. All the WordPress themes I work with follow this pattern.

```
/* Twenty Twenty */

/** 
 * Hide the default logo. 
 *
 * For posts use .postid-1 format.
 */
.page-id-14 .custom-logo-link img {
    display: none;
}

/** 
 * Drop in a different logo.
 *
 * The site link is respected.
 */
.page-id-14 .custom-logo-link {
    background-image: url(https://balistreetphotographer.files.wordpress.com/2019/02/balistreetphotographer-logo-2-slashes-65.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    height: 65px;
    width: 65px;
}
```

Obviously **change** the page/post ID, logo URL, and logo dimensions to yours.

Here's how to get the [page/post ID](https://dev.to/marklchaves/changing-up-header-logos-26c5#page-post-id).

Shout if you have any questions :-)